# How to use a vendor class in a test unit test ? (set the Locale via LaravelLocalization in test )

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit, codeception

In a unit test, I need to set a locale before the test

```
use Mcamara\LaravelLocalization;
...
class FormatHelperTest extends \Codeception\TestCase\Test
{

protected function _before(){
        LaravelLocalization::setLocale('el');
```

However,

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Mcamara\LaravelLocalization' not found in
/vagrant/project1/tests/unit/FormatHelperTest.php on line 40
```

How could I set the Locale via LaravelLocalization in a unit test ?

**Edit**

codeception.yml

```
actor: Tester
paths:
    tests: tests
    log: tests/_output
    data: tests/_data
    support: tests/_support
    envs: tests/_envs
settings:
    bootstrap: _bootstrap.php
    colors: true
    memory_limit: 1024M
extensions:
    enabled:
        - Codeception\Extension\RunFailed
modules:
    config:
        Db:
            dsn: ''
            user: ''
            password: ''
            dump: tests/_data/dump.sql
```

**Edit**

tests/_bootstrap.php

```
<?php
// This is global bootstrap for autoloading
```

test/unit/_boootstrap.php

```
<?php
// Here you can initialize variables that will be available to your tests
```

Comment: Show your codeception.yml files, to see if you're using the autoloader correctly. There's also a `_bootstrap.php` file where you can setup the autoloader to your liking (eg include `vendor/autoload.php`, or register your own autoloader)

Comment: codeception.yml file added, as requested by @EliasVanOotegem

Comment: Also add the contents of `_bootstrap.php` (under settings: bootstrap in the yaml file)

Comment: What happens if you `include` the autoloader in your global bootstrap file? (ie: `include '../vendor/autoload.php';`)